# Chrome browser changed submit button shape

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, button

Since the update to the latest Chrome browser version (42.0.2311.90, 64-bit, on Mac OS X), the shape of all submit buttons has changed -- without me having changed my code at all! 
The buttons are now considerably higher (more empty space above and below the button text) than before. In fact, I have tested this with buttons having no formatting or CSS at all, and the difference to the old button shape and to buttons shown in e.g. Firefox is considerable. Buttons now actually overlap some of my text!

I have not been able to figure out a way to make the buttons narrower again so as to not overlap the text above them.

Surely I cannot be the only one having this issue, but I have searched and not found this issue on this forum. Thanks for your help.

Screenshots:

Button in Chrome browser without the CSS files involved: https://encoding.blitzeinschlag.de/button_chrome_no_css.png

Button in Firefox browser (including the CSS files): https://encoding.blitzeinschlag.de/button_firefox.png

HTML Code of the DIV shown in the screenshots:

```
<p style='margin: 4px 0px 2px 0px; padding: 0; font-size: 13px; font-weight: bold;'>stein20</p>
<p style='margin: 0; '>126% / 27 GB frei</p><p style='margin: 0px; '>WowzaStatus: <b>OK</b></p><p style='margin: 0px; '>Wowza(30m): 100%</p>
<p style='margin: 0; '>W-Speed: 249 MBit/s</p>
<p style='margin: 0; '>24h Avg: 386 MBit/s</p>
<form id='wowza_neustartaktiv_stein20' action='' method='POST'>
<input type='submit' id='wowza_neustart_button_stein20' onclick='wowza_neustart_popup("stein20")' value='Neustart!' style='font-size:10px;'></form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove Chrome's default stylings by setting `-webkit-appearance` to `none`:

```
input[type="submit"] {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```